# How to remove $ from string?

Tags: php, string, api

Iam using `$you_value[$i] = str_replace('$', '', $you_value[$i]);` but it doesnt work

I want to get the value to this link from valve 
https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&currency=1&market_hash_name=Dragonclaw%20Hook

this is my code

```
$you_value[$i] = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&currency=1&market_hash_name=".$you_value[$i]."";
                $you_value[$i] = str_replace('$', '', $you_value[$i]);
                $you_value[$i] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $you_value[$i]);
                $you_value[$i] = file_get_contents($you_value[$i]);
                $you_value[$i] = json_decode($you_value[$i], true);
                $you_success[$i] = $you_value[$i]['success'];
                $you_value[$i] = $you_value[$i]['lowest_price'];
```

my code is working before but i dont know now why it doesnt work

Comment: Your code example isn't actually using `str_replace`, but `preg_replace`. You should have gotten a warning. (If not: enable `error_reporting` whenever something doesn't work.)

Comment: i dont see why you think you need to do the replace at all?

Comment: i need to remove the $ because i want to add values

Comment: not getting it, a real example please

Comment: it is now ok thanks though `    $you_value[$i] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $you_value[$i]);
    $you_value[$i] = file_get_contents($you_value[$i]);
    $you_value[$i] = json_decode($you_value[$i], true);
    $you_success[$i] = $you_value[$i]['success'];
    $you_value[$i] = $you_value[$i]['lowest_price'];
    $you_value[$i] = str_replace('$','', $you_value[$i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the file content

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&currency=1&market_hash_name=Dragonclaw%20Hook');
```

Then make an object of it, decoding the json

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Then repalce the dollar-sign

```
$item_without_dollar_sign = str_replace("$", '', $obj->lowest_price);
```

Result:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=570&currency=1&market_hash_name=Dragonclaw%20Hook');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$item_without_dollar_sign = str_replace("$", '', $obj->lowest_price);
```

Comment: oh, now i understand ;-)